# Error in family:poisson(link = "log") : NA/NaN argument

Tags: r, poisson

I am trying to predict football results using the R built in function `glm()`. However I am getting an `Error in family:poisson(link = "log") : NA/NaN argument`.

The code that I am using is:

```
model <- glm(HomeTeamScore ~ AwayTeamScore + HomeTeam + AwayTeam,
             family:poisson(link = "log"), data = results)
summary(model)
```

Results are as the table below:-

```
Day       Date    HomeTeam    AwayTeam HomeTeamScore AwayTeamScore   Competition
1 Friday 2015-08-14 Aston Villa  Man United             0             1 PremierLeague
2 Monday 2015-08-10   West Brom    Man City             0             3 PremierLeague
3 Monday 2015-08-17   Liverpool Bournemouth             1             0 PremierLeague
4 Monday 2015-08-24     Arsenal   Liverpool             0             0 PremierLeague
5 Monday 2015-09-14    West Ham   Newcastle             2             0 PremierLeague
6 Monday 2015-09-28   West Brom     Everton             2             3 PremierLeague
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `=` rather than `:`

```
family = poisson(link = "log")
```